# label value changes when i assign it to a n object

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

i have a random number assigned to my label and then when i press the button on the website it calls the label and assigns it to an object what the label shows and what it assigns to the object are two different numbers

html

```
<td><asp:Label ID="Ucodelbl" runat="server" Text="Label" Font- 
Size="Large"></asp:Label></td>

<td colspan="2"><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Register" 
OnClick="Button1_Click" /></td>
```

c#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    Ucodelbl.Text = rnd.Next(0, 10000).ToString();
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    u.Ucode = Ucodelbl.Text;
    u.Upass = Upasstxt.Text;
    u.Uname = Unametxt.Text;
    if (pic.HasFile)
    {
        pic.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("mypics/") + pic.FileName);
        u.Upic = pic.FileName;
    }
    s.registerUser(u);
    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
}
```

now the problem that i have is that i assign Ucodelbl a random number in Page_Load

and then in Button1_Click im trying to assign it to u.Ucode but the value that it represented on the page itself when i loaded the website was different then the one inserted to to the u.Ucode

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think using `if (!Page.IsPostBack)` in your `Page_Load` could be what you're after

Comment: As @freefaller said, you need to check `IsPostBack` in your `Page_Load` method.  What's happening is that you assign a random number to the label text and then the button click causes postback which reloads the page and assigns a different number.  Just assign the random number if the page is loading and ispostback is false.

Comment: thank you all it was the IsPostBack. I didnt know that when i click a button it reloads the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click the button, you are posting the page back to the server so the button click event can be handled by your `Button1_Click` event handler.

The problem is that you're running the `Ucodelbl.Text` assignment each time the page loads... meaning that you get a new random number when you first load the page (as intended) but then **again** when you click the button.

To stop that happening, you need to wrap it with an `if` statement based on the [`Page.IsPostBack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.ispostback?view=netframework-4.8) property...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Ucodelbl.Text = rnd.Next(0, 10000).ToString();
    }
}
```